# Inject to static field

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

this is my interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IWeapon
{
   void Shoot();
}

public interface IWarrior
{
   void Kill();
}

public class Killer : IWarrior
{
   private static IWeapon _weapon;

   public void Kill()
   {
       _weapon.Shoot();
   }
}

public class Rifle : IWeapon
{
   public void Shoot()
   {
   }
}
```

How I can inject Rifle in Killer class with Ninject?

Comment: Why would you want `_weapon` to be static in the first place? Surely two different killers could have different weapons...

Comment: The finantial crysis hits killers too: one type of weapon only available...:)

Comment: You can use [InSingletonScope](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/) if you want only one  instance.

Comment: It is example interfaces and classes which describe my problem :-) The reason why I want _weapon to be static is because real field should have only one instance between multithread application.

Comment: You can still achieve that by managing the scope correctly.. you can read about them here: http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/ you probably want it to be InScope

Comment: Anurag Ranjhan, Baz1nga, thank you!

Comment: You seem to confuse something: Making _weapon a static field means all killers have the same _weapon. What you want is making your weapons Singleton objects which means that only one instance of each weapon exist.

Comment: No, i want that all killers have the same _weapon :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject does not inject statics because this should be done using InSingletonScope. It does not support field injection too, because fields should not be accessed from outside a class. Use constructor or property injection instead.